# how to create a list using double brackets to extract elements

Tags: r, apply

```
L <- list(a= c(1,3,5), b= c(2,3,4,1), c= c(4,7))
v <- c(3,2,4)
```

as shown below

```
> L[[1]]+3
[1] 4 6 8
> L[[2]]+2
[1] 4 5 6 3
> L[[3]]+4
[1]  8 11
```

I wish to get the result as

```
list(a= c(4,6,8), b= c(4,5,6,3), c= c(8,11))
```

is it possible to use an APPLY function to that?

Comment: you just need `mapply("+", L, v)`

Comment: or `purrr::map2(L, v, `+`)` if you want a tidyverse solution (which is doing the same as `mapply`)

Comment: wow! that's great! Thanks so much

Comment: It's safer to use `Map(\`+\`, L, v)` or `mapply(\`+\`, L, v, simplify = FALSE)` because otherwise if the lengths of `L` happen to be identical you'll get a matrix out instead of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, I could not find a duplicate for this. I'll post an answer.

We can use `mapply` to add elements in list.

```
mapply("+", L, v)

#$a
#[1] 4 6 8

#$b
#[1] 4 5 6 3

#$c
#[1]  8 11
```

Comment: Or a bit more safely with `Map(`+`, L, v)` as suggested by @alistaire.

Answer (score 0):

With `lapply()`:

```
L[] <- lapply(1:3, function(i) L[[i]] + v[i])
L

$a
[1] 4 6 8

$b
[1] 4 5 6 3

$c
[1]  8 11
```